# "The domain policy has disabled third-party Drive apps"

Tags: google-drive-api

For some domains our application does not work. I've check their Google Apps domain configuration and Google Drive is enabled.
Any ideas?

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 OK
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "The domain policy has disabled third-party Drive apps",
    "reason" : "domainPolicy"
  } ],
  "message" : "The domain policy has disabled third-party Drive apps"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:143)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.execute(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:187)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClient.executeUnparsed(GoogleClient.java:279)
    at com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpRequest.executeUnparsed(JsonHttpRequest.java:207)
    at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Insert.executeUnparsed(Drive.java:307)
    at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Insert.execute(Drive.java:331)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Even though the Google Drive Service is enabled for users, an administrator can restrict users from installing Google Drive apps or making use of the Google Drive API by going to Apps > Google Apps > Settings for Drive then unchecking "Allow users to install Google Drive apps" in the "Data Access" menu.

The error message you are seeing indicates that these domains have "Allow users to install Google Drive apps" unchecked. Your application should handle this error by giving a message to the user along the lines of:

`Sorry, you cannot use this application because your administrator has disabled 3rd party Google Drive apps. Please ask your administrator to allow Google Drive apps by opening the Google Apps control panel and going to Apps > Google Apps > Settings for Drive and making sure "Allow users to install Google Drive apps" in the "Data Access" menu is enabled.`

Comment: I just add to check this for a Zapier Google Sheets integration but I found it here: "Apps > G Suite > Settings for Drive and Docs" and checked "Allow users to access Google Drive with the Drive SDK API"